# How to plot a 3d surface from multiple 2d arrays and one 1d array?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the following data so it will look like the attached image:
each text file is a 2X40 matrix.

xi,yi lines should be offset in the Z direction according the z array.
I want to connect those line by a surface

```
z = np.array([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5])

x0, y0 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=0.5.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x1, y1 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=1.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x2, y2 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=1.5.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x3, y3 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=2.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x4, y4 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=2.5.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x5, y5 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=3.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x6, y6 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=3.3.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x7, y7 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=3.5.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x8, y8 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=4.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x9, y9 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=4.5.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x10, y10 = np.loadtxt('Conv_Vd(Vk)_Vg=5.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
```

[image]

Comment: What does x0 and y0 etc. look like? It is not clear at all what your data actually is. When you ask a question here, please stop for one second and consider what information is necessary to tell someone who doesn't know anything about what you are trying to do. It es expected that you provide a minimal reproducible example, and your example is not reproducible since we don't have the text files and can't guess what they contain.

Comment: I know that the task is easy and solvable even without knowing the content of the files. even arrays with random size will work just fine !

Comment: We heard that one before and then it turned out that the array shape was (,,12) or the array contained datetime objects in Kisuaheli or whatever, and that's why the solution did not work. There is a reason the SO guidelines ask you to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to attract good, non-generic answers.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [3D wireframe plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/wire3d.html) which means you need to coerce your data into an x,y,z format. Conventionally 'z' would be the dependent variable. Guessing at your current data structure, you have a bunch of sets of x,y where x is indepenent and y is the dependent. You then want to add a new 'depth' dimension which you are calling 'z'.

You need to end up with 3 1D arrays x,y,z. You can simply concatenate your existing x1,x2,x3..., y1,y2,y3... arrays, and create a 'z' array of the same final size, containing the z values you are prescribing. Then feed it all into `plot_wireframe`, remembering that you are swapping the y and z convention.